# Basic properties of the conditional expectation in Banach spaces

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis

Let

- $E_1$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $E_2$ be a separable $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal A$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$
- $X$ be an $\mathfrak L(E_1,E_2)$-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $Y$ be an $E_1$-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$

I want to show, that if $X\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P,\mathfrak L(E_1,E_2))$, $XY\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P,E_2)$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable, then $$\operatorname E\left[XY\mid\mathcal F\right]=\operatorname E\left[X\mid\mathcal F\right]\:Y\;.\tag 1$$

If $E_1=E_2=\mathbb R$, then $(1)$ is an elementary result and I know how to prove it. How can we prove it in the more general case described here?

Besides the proof of $(1)$, I wonder if all the basic properties (like the "tower property", etc.) of the conditional expectation in the real-valued case generalize to the Banach space case. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any textbook which gives more than a simple existence/uniqueness result of the conditional expectation in Banach spaces. So, I would be happy if someone could give me a good reference.

Comment: Are you willing to assume $E_2$ is a dual space?

Comment: @UriBader No, but I'm willing to assume that $E_1,E_2$ are separable Hilbert spaces or that $E_2$ admits a Schauder basis.

Comment: You need an assumption on the integrability of $X$, don't you?

Comment: @NateEldredge Of course! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I realize that I don't understand the question. The LHS is an $\mathcal{F}$ measurable but the RHS only $A$ measurable. Maybe you assume $Y$ is F measurable?

Comment: @UriBader I wrote: "If ... and $Y$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable ..."

Comment: Missed that. Sorry. Then I think this is OK (though you need $E_2$ to be a dual space, e.g Hilbert). One should be able to reduce the question to the case $\mathcal{F}$ is trivial, by integration over fibers, and then it pretty much follows from the definitions. But details need to be checked and I prefer to leave it to someone who is more fluent than I am at this.

Comment: You don't want to assume that $E_2$ is a dual space but a nevertheless Hilbert???

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I've misunderstood Uri. I thought he would ask if I'm willing to assume that $E_2$ is the topological dual space of $E_1$.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could give a reference to where you are reading the definition, existence/uniqueness proof, etc, so that people have a clear sense of what you are assuming and what you know.  I am not sure, but there could potentially be some issues in defining $E[X \mid \mathcal{F}]$, since $X$ takes values in the non-separable Banach space $\mathfrak{L}(E_1, E_2)$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've read the definition and existence/uniqueness in the books of Da Prato (Stochastic Equations in infinite dimensions) and Röckner (Stochastic Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction). $\mathfrak L(E_1,E_2)$ *is* separable, since $E_2$ is separable.

Comment: @NateEldredge Meanwhile I've found some books (e.g. *Vector Integration and Stochastic Integration in Banach Spaces*  by *Nicolae Dinculeanu*) which state that "the usual properties" remain valid. However, they don't give a proof and hence I assume it's trivial to see.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Re separability, no, that's not true.  Consider for instance the case where $E_1 = E_2 = H$ is a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, \dots$.  Consider infinite permutation matrices, i.e. for any bijection $\sigma : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ let $T_\sigma$ be the unique bounded operator with $T e_i = e_{\sigma(i)}$.  Then there are uncountably many $T_\sigma$ and the operator norm distance between any two of them is at least $\sqrt{2}$.  So $\mathfrak{L}(H,H)$ is not separable.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm sorry, you're right. What I've got in mind was that $\mathfrak L(E_1,E_2)$ is complete, since $E_2$ is complete.

Comment: @NateEldredge Actually, I was only aware of existence results for conditional expectations in the case of separable Banach spaces. However, I've found some [lecture notes](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~czaja/ISEM/internetseminar200708.pdf) in which the author proves the existence for an arbitrary Banach space (see Theorem 11.10 on page 155). Below the proof the author is stating that Proposition 11.6 (3) extends to the Banach space case. Unfortunately, it's not clear which kind of extension he has in mind. $(1)$ is obviously a candidate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes in full generality. You don't need the separability assumption on $E_2$ and the integrability assumption on $XY$ (though clearly you do have to assume that $X\in L^1(\Omega,L(E_1,E_2))$). In comments to the question I was concerned about $E_2$ being a dual space, but that was based on my own confusion and it is irrlevant.

Let me first note that if $\mathcal{F}$ is trivial then $Y$ is simply a vector in $E_1$ and your equation reads 
$$ (*)\quad E[X]Y=E[XY]$$ 
and is straight forward to prove.

For the genral case, I prefer to think of $\mathcal{F}$ as a factor. That is, I consider a measurable map $\pi:\Omega \to \Omega'$ where $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}',P')$ is another probability space in which the points are separated, $\mathcal{F}=\pi^*\mathcal{A}$ and $P'=\pi_*P$. It is known that such a space exists (and it is unique in an apropriate sense)
and for every $\mathcal{F}$-measurable map $Z:\Omega\to E$ there exists an $\mathcal{A}'$-measurable map $Z':\Omega'\to E_1$ such that $Z=Z'\circ\pi$.
We say that $Z$ is the *pull-back* of $Z'$.

Now we can *disintegrate* the measure $P$ over $P'$. That is, for a.e $\omega'\in\Omega'$ there exists a probability measure $P_{\omega'}$ on $\Omega_{\omega'}:=\pi^{-1}(\{\omega'\})$ (varying measurably wrt $\mathcal{A}$) such that $P=\int_{\Omega'} P_{\omega'}dP(\omega')$.
For every Banach space $E$ and $\mathcal{A}$-measurable map $Z:\Omega\to E$,
given $\omega'\in\Omega'$ we may consider the restriction $Z_{\omega'}:=Z|_{\Omega_{\omega'}}$ and its expectation wrt $P_{\omega'}$. This defines a function $Z':\Omega'\to E$. It is a basic fact that the conditional expectation $E(Z\mid \mathcal{F})$ is the pull back $Z'$.

The equation $E[XY\mid \mathcal{F}]=E[X\mid\mathcal{F}]Y$ now becomes simply the equation $(*)$, when reduced to the fibers of $\pi$. Indeed, fixing $\omega'\in\Omega'$ and applying $(*)$ for $X_{\omega'}$ and $Y'(\omega')$ (instead of $X$ and $Y$) we get $E[X_{\omega'}]Y(\omega')=E[X_{\omega'}Y(\omega')]$ and pulling back we get the required equation.

Let me conclude by the personal remark that I (a.s) prefer to think geometrically, replacing subalgebras by factors and conditional expectation by integration over fibers. In particular, I prefer "integral" over "expextation". Nevertheless, I am well aware of some advantages of the "probabilistic" mind set over the "geometric" one.

Comment: There is a remaining problem discussed in the comments below the question: Does $\operatorname E\left[X\mid\mathcal F\right]$ exist, even when $X$ takes values in a non-separable space?

Comment: @0xbadf00d In my answer I didn't discuss the definition of what $L^1(\Omega,E)$ is. I assume (as is standard) that the functions there are strongly measurable, hence have (essentially) separable images. Are you using a different convention?

Comment: Also I am assuming throughout that $\Omega$ is  standard Borel space, eg $[0,1]$.

Comment: What is strongly measurable? Why do you assume that $\Omega$ is standar Borel space? Please, could you give me a reference where to find it.